# How to set the value to a TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set a value to the `TextFormField` in `flutter`.

But I couldn't find a way to do that.

this is how my `widget` looks like:

```
Widget _showHeadlineField() {
      return TextFormField(
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onEditingComplete: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionNode);
        },
        controller: _headlineController,

        validator: (headline) {
          if (headline == null || headline.isEmpty) {
            return "Headline cannot be empty";
          }
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Headline",
          hintText: "Covid-19 new stats",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),

        ),
      );
    }
```

I even tried `initialValue` but doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
_headlineController.text = 'Your text';
```

Or when you create controller :

```
 _headlineController = TextEditingController(text: 'Your text')
```

Comment: Thank you! This helpes